# How to make sure that all required wal files are availables before starting a standby server?

Tags: postgresql, replication, restore, point-in-time-recovery

Im writing a script to restore a postgres standby server that was out of sync with the master node for a while.
I would like the following behavior

1. Check if i can go with pg_rewind
2. If pg_rewind fails, then use pg_basebackup

The big deal for me is about the pg_rewind because even if pg_rewind succeeds, it does not guarantee that the standby server will start successfully. In some cases the standby server needs some old wal file of the master (which can be provided using `restore_command`) and if it is not found, you get this :  `ERROR: requested WAL segment 00000002000000050000007C has already been removed`

So i would like, in addition to pg_rewind successful response, to find a way to ensure that every wal file that will be required on server startup is already available before starting the server. And if it is not available, I continue directly with the second option (perform a full backup with pg_basebackup)

Any help ...

Answer (score 0):

`restore_command` should read files from the archive, and it is your responsibility not to delete archived WAL segments you still need for catching up or `pg_rewind`. So with a WAL archive and a correctly configured `restore_command`, this will not happen.

The alternative is to use replication slots with replication. You have to set `primary_slot_name` on the standby to the name of the replication slot you created. When `pg_rewind` fails, take the backup with

```bash
pg_basebackup --slot=slotname ...
```

Then you can be certain that the primary will retain all the WAL the standby needs. The risk is that the primary can run out of disk space if the standby stays down for too long, so you had better set `max_slot_wal_keep_size` on the primary to prevent that.

Comment: I understand your recommendations. but the problem is that we can't keep the wal files indefinitely since it takes up space.
in my case the repository of archived wal files is configured as a FIFO Cache not exceeding 1Gb. therefore I cannot guarantee the availability of wal files at all times

Comment: 1GB is ridiculously small.